# I am working on a Laravel 8 project in which I want to keep the old value in select option in the blade file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I know this question is asked many time but don't know why solution is not working for me. I am a beginner and have a very simple confusion. I have a form in Laravel blade with a drop down. Now I want to keep the drop down value selected after the user submit the form. This is the code I applied to make it work from internet but don't know why it is not working.

```html
<select class="form-control" name="company">
    <option value="select">Select Type</option>
    <option value="Apple" {{ old('company') == "Apple" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Apple</option>
    <option value="Google" {{ old('company') =="Google" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Google</option>
    <option value="Mi" {{ old('company') == "Mi"? 'selected' : '' }}>Mi</option>
    <option value="Samsung" {{ old('company') == "Samsung" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Samsung</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm assuming your mean keep the old value when you submit, validation fails and you reload the same form again?

Comment: yes exactly this.

Comment: `old` works with the session so make sure you're not using routes defined in `api.php` to handle the submission.

Comment: Oh ok. But actually I dont have any user login in my website. It is just a simple calculator kind of a thing. Also I tried to make this change 'selected' to 'selected="selected" but it didn't worked. Is there any way I can do this without any session? I am a complete beginner so I am building just a simple calculator without user authorization.

Comment: I am using web.php to handle the routes

Comment: can you add the validation code

Comment: Yes sure. here it is. 
'''
$validated = $request->validate([
            'company' => 'required|max:191',
            'valuation' => 'required|max:191',
            
        ]);
'''
I have written this in the controller.

Comment: are you using ->withInput() when you return the error?

Comment: Yes, I am using it like this, -> with('status', 'Wrong Input');

Comment: try to add it to your code like this: ->with('status', 'Wrong Input')->withInput();

Comment: It is just a simple calculator which displays the valuation of company from dollars to Indian Rupee when a particular company is selected it simply multiplies the dollar amount by 75 and displays the result. So what I want is that I am displaying the result on the same page but the drop down options get refreshed and it do not show the selected result. For the second input field I used {{ Request::get('valuation_in_dollar') }} to retain the old value.

Comment: I tried with ->with('status', 'Wrong Input')->withInput(); . It is now giving an error "ErrorException Undefined offset: 0"

Comment: Hi, i got the solution. Thank you for your help. It lead me to think differently. I just replaced the "old()" with "Request::get()" and it solved the issue.

<select class="form-control" name="company">
    <option value="select">Select Type</option>
    <option value="Apple" {{ Request::get('company') == "Apple" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Apple</option>